# Multi selection drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem in some Html and CSS code that i want to do multi selection drop down menu but i face a problem.

what i want to do is something like that :

[image: i want to do something like that]

and what i have done so far is

[image]

and here is my Html code :

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default"
            data-toggle="dropdown" title="Columns">
        Columns
        <b class="caret">
        </b>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <label class="checkbox">

                <input type="checkbox" name="multiselect" value="cheese">Cheese</input>

            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label class="checkbox">

                <input type="checkbox" name="multiselect" value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</input>

            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label class="checkbox">

                <input type="checkbox" name="multiselect" value="mozarella">Mozzarella</input>

            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label class="checkbox">

                <input type="checkbox" name="multiselect" value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</input>

            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label class="checkbox">

                <input type="checkbox" name="multiselect" value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</input>

            </label>

        </li>
        <li>
            <label class="checkbox">

                <input type="checkbox" name="multiselect" value="onions">Onions</input>

            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and my css code :

```
   ul.dropdown-menu {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}

ul.dropdown-menu li {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;

}
ul.dropdown-menu li label {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 40px;
}
```

**My problem is that when i choose any check box input the block disappear and i should open it again to select values !.**

i need some help please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try like this

```
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation(); // it will not propagate the action to parent for closing
});
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how could i add scroll bar ?  because the list is to long

Comment: you can add `overflow-y:scroll, height:<some height>`

Comment: What about horizontal scrolling please?

Comment: better ux and my suggestion should be hide because normally people don't use horizontal

Comment: you saved my little a**

Comment: @ThePoet hahaha ;)

Comment: Is there any other way to do this? Because I have nearly 10-12 drop downs in my page and I dont want this to get called each time..

Comment: @User-8017771 This is the only way you can stop the propogation

Answer (score 0):

Text-indent is negative, thereby it is pulling the checkbox. Please remove that property and see what happens.

Comment: there is no change

Comment: I edited my question and i solve the indent problem but what about disappear problem ?

Answer (score 0):

> It may helps you :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="button-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span>Choose
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="multiselect" value="cheese">Cheese</input>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="multiselect" value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</input>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="multiselect" value="mozarella">Mozzarella</input>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="multiselect" value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</input>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="multiselect" value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</input>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="multiselect" value="onions">Onions</input>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```